# Is Classic Spring MVC Deprecated?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have been reading the [spring reference for version 3.1.x](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) trying to find how to use the classic MVC controllers (e.g. [MultiActionController](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/multiaction/MultiActionController.html), [AbstractController](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractController.html), et. al.).

The only thing I have found is the section for use of the [classic Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#clasic-spring-mvc) with only an ellipsis (...) as content.

Anyway, I have not seen the deprecation notice in the Javadoc. Is the classic Spring MVC usage officially deprecated? Since which version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BaseCommandController](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/BaseCommandController.html) and its subclasses have been deprecated since Spring 3.0 in favour of annotation based controllers.